# UNION ALL одновременно с двух разных серверов phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, union

есть два разных сервера, необходимо сделать запрос к каждому из них и сделать union all с этими двумя запросами, поискав в интернете не нашёл особо информации по этому поводу, когда всё было на одном сервере проблем не возникало, а сейчас неизвестно как можно решить данную проблему
Код старого запроса (uni-ugresha_colportal была одной базой, а uni-ugresha_portal второй):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT time, CONCAT( person.last_name, ' ',SUBSTR(person.name,1,1), '.' ,SUBSTR(person.middle_name,1,1), '.') AS fio, odd, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.person.name AS imya, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.person.middle_name AS fam, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.person.last_name AS otch , `uni-ugresha_colportal`.days.day, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.subject.name AS predmet, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.nedelya.ned, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.groups.name AS groop, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.class.number AS class, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.id_class, sub_group, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.day AS den, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.odd AS chet, `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.id 
      FROM `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_colportal`.days ON `uni-ugresha_colportal`.days.id = `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.day 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_colportal`.class ON `uni-ugresha_colportal`.class.id = `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.id_class 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_colportal`.person ON `uni-ugresha_colportal`.person.id = `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.id_teacher 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_colportal`.nedelya ON `uni-ugresha_colportal`.nedelya.id = `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.odd 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_colportal`.subject ON `uni-ugresha_colportal`.subject.id = `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.id_subject 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_colportal`.groups ON `uni-ugresha_colportal`.groups.id = `uni-ugresha_colportal`.schedule.id_group 
      WHERE `uni-ugresha_colportal`.class.number = '" . $_GET['cab'] . "' AND (".$zapros.") 
    UNION ALL
      SELECT time, CONCAT( person.last_name, ' ',SUBSTR(person.name,1,1), '.' ,SUBSTR(person.middle_name,1,1), '.') AS fio, odd, `uni-ugresha_portal`.person.name AS imya, `uni-ugresha_portal`.person.middle_name AS fam, `uni-ugresha_portal`.person.last_name AS otch , `uni-ugresha_portal`.days.day, `uni-ugresha_portal`.subject.name AS predmet, `uni-ugresha_portal`.nedelya.ned, `uni-ugresha_portal`.groups.name AS groop, `uni-ugresha_portal`.class.number AS class, `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.id_class, sub_group, `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.day AS den, `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.odd AS chet, `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.id 
      FROM `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_portal`.days ON `uni-ugresha_portal`.days.id = `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.day 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_portal`.class ON `uni-ugresha_portal`.class.id = `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.id_class 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_portal`.person ON `uni-ugresha_portal`.person.id = `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.id_teacher 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_portal`.nedelya ON `uni-ugresha_portal`.nedelya.id = `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.odd 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_portal`.subject ON `uni-ugresha_portal`.subject.id = `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.id_subject 
      INNER JOIN `uni-ugresha_portal`.groups ON `uni-ugresha_portal`.groups.id = `uni-ugresha_portal`.schedule.id_group 
      WHERE `uni-ugresha_portal`.class.number = '" . $_GET['cab'] . "' AND (".$zapros2.")   ) as tt 
ORDER BY  time ASC,den,odd,sub_group
```

Comment: [The FEDERATED Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

Comment: *есть два разных сервера* Это точно два разных СЕРВЕРА? а не две разных базы данных на одном сервере? Если всё же серверы - это разные инстансы на одном хосте, или они на разных инстансах ОС? Если последнее - они в раамках одного VMM хоста, или это физически разные серверы?

Comment: То что я скинул код действительно работал на одном сервере, но сейчас необходимо делать запросы на два разных сервера, так как это 2 разных аккаунта на хостинге, 1 сервер это обычный общий хостинг на JINO на одном аккаунте, а второй это виртуальный сервер на CENT OS также на JINO уже на втором аккаунте, я думал может есть какой-то автоматический способ выполнять импорт одной таблицы, так как по сути это просто объединенное расписание по кабинетам университета и колледжа http://colportal.uni-college.ru/raspt/cab.php?cab=304

Comment: Вообще по сути запрос UNION выполняется только для последующей сортировки вывода, что бы отсортировать два запроса по паре, дню, чётности не чётности недели и подгруппе, может быть эту сортировку можно выполнить и посредством php, но плохо представляю как можно выполнить сортировку 2 результатов без mysql

Comment: И да, у php конечно есть функции сортировки, но если из mysql придут уже отсортированные выборки, то я бы наверное сделал бы это вручную, используя метод "сортировка слиянием". т.е. фактически параллельно идете по 2м выборкам и на выход пишите ту строку что меньше и сдвигаете указатель в этой выборке

Comment: Ну да в принципе как я и уже и думал сделать, ладно, просто хотелось узнать можно ли вообще как-то использовать запросы одновременно с двух серверов